# What's the best way to fix this IE7 bug (cursor of the floatted/block span into an a)

Tags: html, css

I think this is a common IE7 problem.
When I insert a `span` (`block` or `floated`) into an `a` the cursor of the link vanish.

```
<a class='myLink' href=http://www.link.com>
    <span class='mySpan'>There isn't the cursor</span>
</a>

.myLink
{       
    text-decoration:none;
}

.mySpan
{
    float:left; 
}
```

my solution usually is to put `cursor:pointer;` in the span... but maybe there is a more correct way. Do you know?

Comment: Are we talking generally or specific to this situation? Because at present there is no reason to use a `span` in your `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this - http://robertnyman.com/2008/01/22/cant-make-links-appear-clickable-in-ie/

It seems that if the span gets it's 'haslayout' property set as it does in your example due to the '`float:left`' then the link cursor is removed. If you remove the '`float:left`' then the link cursor appears again. There are a number of solutions mentioned in the link but I think your best/simplest bet would be -

```
a span {
   cursor: pointer; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to float the span inside the link, cursor:pointer is the way to go.